# Java - Dynamic instantiation of new objects

Tags: java, oop, reflection

I'm a fairly-new developer in the process of writing a Java application that needs to create objects dynamically. These objects are unique and need to be uniquely referenced, but are all part of the same generic data class with the same attributes. Each of these attributes is a `String`, and they are:

- the `value` of the data
- the `source` of the data
- a reference `interfaceCode` that enables me to place the data in the correct location in an interfacing system
- a reference `parent` that ties the data object to a parent object representing a data classification used in the interfacing system

And getters/setters for each. Values for each of those attributes is set using setters called in the public constructor with two arguments passed in. Here is a code sample:

```
class DataObject {

private String value, source, interfaceCode, parent;

    public DataObject(String arg1, String arg2) {

    setValue(arg1);
    setSource(arg2);
    setInterfaceCode(arg2);
    setParent(arg2);

    }

    //setters/getters here
    /
    /
    /
}
```

The issue I'm running into is determining how to create these objects uniquely and dynamically - I have input code that reads a data source document and pulls out data I want. If it finds data of a certain source type (which occur once per document), it needs to create a new `Data Object` and assign the values to that. This reference is intended to be stored in a `HashMap<String,DataObject` with the `String` describing the data source set as a key and the `DataObject` reference being the value assigned. This is all run in a different Class, as you can see below:

```
class DataParser {

private String value, source;
protected static HashMap<String, DataObject> dataObjects = new HashMap<String,DataObject>();

    public void DataParser() {

        if (value != null && source != null) {

             dataObjects.put((source), new DataObject(source, value));

        }

    }

    public HashMap<String,DataObject> getHashMap() {

        return dataObjects;

    }

    //data setter/getter here to grab data from data source and provide access
    /
    /
    /
}
```

So, I've read a whole bunch of StackOverflow posts/questions on this and I'm still coming up short. From many of the answers, I thought this problem might require reflection. However, I'm a little overwhelmed by the topic and not really sure if this is the correct route.

My concern is that, with my original code, that `DataObject` reference from `newData` will simply be overwritten each time I instantiate a new `DataObject`. Ideally, I would have it instantiate a new Object with a variable name equivalent to the value of `source`, but this is entirely unnecessary - what matters is the reference.

Can someone point me in the right direction regarding this problem?

**Edit:** It seems I wasn't asking the correct questions originally, it seems. But the quick discussion I had with folks in the comments helped me figure out the right question to ask, which led me to the correct answer through Google. I've updated the code in DataParser to show my solution.

This problem is technically solved now.

Comment: If you know the object to be instantiated is a `DataObject`, and the class has a public constructor, then you shouldn't need Reflection: just write `DataObject data = new DataObject(...values from input data...);`. Then store it in a map, etc., as needed.

Comment: This won't result in an overwritten reference when another `DataObject` with the reference `data` is created, with different `value` and `source` constructor args?

Comment: Object references are usually stored somewhere. If you store a given reference into, say, a local variable, then obviously any reassignment of this variable in the same method execution will result in the previous reference being overwritten. You mentioned a map for storing such objects, though.

Comment: Yes, the intention is to map each `DataObject` as it is created to the value of `source` (ex: `source = "A"`) - but unless I am misunderstanding, this simply maps the reference to that instantiation of `DataObject`. Won't a new instantiation with the same local variable, but mapped to different `value` of `source` (`source = "B"`) will result in the new reference value overwriting the value stored to "A"?

Comment: @drs If you set a DataObject equal to the same as another DataObject (DataObj = DataObj2) then the map will get rid of one of these DataObjects because maps do not allow duplicate values.  The values you send to the DataObject will not deter what is removed because of duplication in a Map.  Because technically even if two DataObjects have the same values visually, they're both different instances of values.

This is why you could want to check your values against the other values before creating the new object, just to make sure there aren't duplicates.

Comment: So the local variable reference (this would be stored in a Method) is irrelevant, then? Only the key within the Map?

If the following code (`DataObject newData = new DataObject(source, value);`  and `DataObjectHash.put((source), newData)`) runs inside a method, and that method is called twice for two different values of `source` (assume that the value of `source` is changed between method calls), the stored reference value change for the first Mapped instance of `DataObject`?

Comment: If you execute `map.put("A", dataObj1);` then `map.put("B", dataObj2)`, the map will store two entries holding different references.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but that's not what I'm trying to do. I want to instantiate unique `DataObject`s dynamically each time `source` and `value` are assigned new values, without having to declare a different variable name.

Assume the following: method call assigns `source="A"`, and a new DataObject is instantiated as `newData`. I execute `map.put((source), newData`). Now a new method call assigns `source="B"`. I want to make a constructor call to create another `DataObject` with  a randomly assigned reference during runtime, and then execute `map.put((source), newData`).

Comment: However, each instantiated `DataObject` should have a different reference  because the data attributed to each is unique. I want to know if its possible to do this without using unique local variables for each instantiation, since I want this to occur during runtime as data is pulled dynamically from sources.

Comment: I figured it out - I created the static method with the following code `createDataDoc(String source, String value) { dataObjects.put((source), new dataObject(source, value)); }` This enables me to create the generically-referenced `DataObject`s on the fly as values to `HashMap` keys  in the HashMap `dataObjects` equivalent to the value of `source` at that time.